# Getting contents of element without tags

Tags: jquery

On click I have:

```
p.changePage = function(e){
    console.log(e.currentTarget);
}
```

This gives me:

```
<a href="#">1</a>
```

How can I get just the figure '1'?

I've tried:

```
console.log(e.currentTarget.innerHtml());
```

Also, is this a good way to get a number from an element or would it be best to store it on something like data-id?

Comment: I would recommend data-id if you are going to use this further for selection of element and need further processing of it. Do not rely on what you are showing, rather rely on storing ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See there are a number of ways you can achiveve this

```
e.currentTarget.innerHTML,
e.currentTarget.textContent
```

or you can use jQuery

```
$(e.currentTarget).html(),
$(e.currentTarget).text()
```

But if you have child elements for this target element then these may give undesired results.
So I think that your last line is completely valid and must put this value as an attribute to the target element in order to fetch it currectly.